# Highlighting cell using if condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, conditional-statements

Here is my excel sheet:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|   |    A     |     B    |     C    |    D     |      E       |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 | Question | Option A | Option B | Option C | Right Answer |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 2 | Date     | 15/4/19  | 25/4/19  | None     |      B       |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

As the right answer is **OPTION B** i.e `C2`. How can I highlight cell C2 using *if* condition?

I tried one using conditional formatting but it didn't give me the result.

Using Microsoft Excel 2016

[image: What I tried in ms excel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use three rules, one for each column:

- `=$E2="A"` applies to `=$B$2:$B$n` (where `n` is the last row in your table)
- `=$E2="B"` applies to `=$C$2:$C$n`
- `=$E2="C"` applies to `=$D$2:$D$n`

[image: conditional rules]

[image: result]

Bear in mind:

- In Excel, equality is tested using a single `=`
- A formula is introduced using `=`
- The `if()` is not required, unless you use `if(..., TRUE, FALSE)`, which is redundant.
- You're testing the `E` column, starting from the `2` row, thus use `$E2`

Comment: You can also use `OR` function